# Connect AWS Athena to Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena, connector

I need to connect AWS Athena (which is binded to AWS s3 bucket) to a Postgres SQL database.

I have tried to connect with Tableau and PowerBI successfully (following the instructions in documentation) and the result was successful.

I think that I need to use the JDBC connector already installed on my machine and try to create a server in Postgres, but I cannot see any option in pgadmin in order to connect AWS athena to the server.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/query-any-data-source-with-amazon-athenas-new-federated-query/

Comment: thank you jordan. but the documentation attached is regarding the possibility to get data from any source to athena. I need to connect postgresql to athena in order to get data from s3 bucket and store the data in dedicated tables

Comment: typically you would use AWS glue for that

Comment: @demiurgo86 Are you saying that you want to run a query in the PostgreSQL database that will then call Athena to query data stored in Amazon S3? Also, what do you mean by "I have tried to connect with Tableau and PowerBI successfully" -- what did you connect to what, and how did you use it?

Comment: @Rotenstein yes, my purpose is to run a query in postgresql over aws athena. Why this? Because there are restrictions (company policy) on aws glue usage, so the only data exposed are available from aws athena. Powerbi and tableau have been connected with related connectors to Aws athena, according to the provided instructions on tableau documentation and powerbi docs website.